# Object doesn't support this property or method while getting the first result of bing search

Tags: vba, excel, internet-explorer

I am trying to get the link first result of bing search:

> Sample url: https://www.bing.com/search?q=Lancaster University Statistics and Operational Research with Industrial Applications MRes

but I am getting run time error 438 on this line:

> Set objLink = objResultDiv.getelementsbytagname("a")(0)  'Error here

```
Sub getURL()

Dim objIE As Object
Dim i As Long, fI As Long
Dim fURL
Dim objResultDiv
Dim objLink

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

fI = INP.Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

Set objIE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

With objIE
  .Visible = True
  .Silent = True
    For i = 1 To fI

        .Navigate INP.Range("D" & i).Value

        Do While .Busy Or .readyState <> 4
            DoEvents
        Loop

        fURL = Empty


        Set objResultDiv = objIE.document.getelementsbyclassname("b_algo")
        Set objLink = objResultDiv.getelementsbytagname("a")(0)  'Error here

        INP.Range("E" & i) = objLink.href

    Next i

End With

  objIE.Quit
  Set objIE = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: What is INP? Where is it declared?

Comment: @danieltakeshi INP is name of the worksheet defined in the properties window of the worksheet

Comment: The error means `objResultDiv` doesn't have a `getelementsbytagname` member, i.e. you're not working with the object type you think you're working with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

getElementsByClassname returns a collection of elements.  So you'll need to specify which one to return.  For example, to return the first element (index starts at 0)...

```
Set objResultDiv = objIE.document.getElementsByClassname("b_algo")(0)
```

Hope this helps!